# List controllers are not supported for ProcessInstance

Tags: apex

Is there a workaround for "List controllers are not supported for ProcessInstance" error in visualforce page?

Am creating a simple visualforce page to display the ProcessInstance records in a page block table with the pagination using standard set controller, but i am getting above error. How i can solve above error.

I can't use soql query with offset because we are having 2000+ records.
Below is my short code.

```
String accQuery = 'select id from ProcessInstance';
database.query(accquery);

ApexPages.StandardSetController con = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(accQuery));

system.debug('@######'+con);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have added small part of code.

Comment: you can try with jquery plugin that will make pagination at client side. let me if you need any help on this

Answer (score 1):

Consider implementing Client side pagination using JS Remoting. As it follows stateful client and Stateless server architecture, so you won't have to be worried about viewstat. This is also way better in terms of performance and you also have the control over UI.

**Otherwise you can always go for any jQuery plugins.**

I have recently implemented below code for cient side pagination using wrapper classes and JS Remoting.

```
@RemoteAction
    Global static Object[] articleListing(String selectedCategory,String searchedString){
        Integer pageNumber = 10;

    List<Object> articles = new List<Object>();

    List<sObject> articleList = new List<sObject>();

    Integer index=1;
    Integer articleStartIndex = articles.size();

    List<sObject> results = ansPKB_KnowledgeHelper.getArticlesSOQL(searchedString,selectedCategory,Null);

    if(!results.isEmpty()){

        for(sObject article : results){

            if(index < pageSize){
                index++;
                articleList.add(article);
            }
            else{
                index = 1;
                articleList.add(article);
                if(pageNumber==1)
                    articles.add(new ansPKB_Pagination(False,False,True,True,articleList));
                else
                    articles.add(new ansPKB_Pagination(True,True,True,True,articleList));
                pageNumber++;    
                articleList = new List<sObject>();   
            }
        }

        ansPKB_Pagination pagination;
        if(articleList.size()>0){
            //if this is the only page
            if(articleStartIndex == articles.size()){
                articles.add(new ansPKB_Pagination(False,False,False,False,articleList));
            }
            // If a page already exist
            else if(articleStartIndex < articles.size()){
                articles.add(new ansPKB_Pagination(True,True,False,False,articleList));
            }

        }
        //Mark the last pagination set as Last
        else{
            //If there is only a single page
            if(articleStartIndex+1 == articles.size()){
                pagination =  (ansPKB_Pagination)articles.get(articles.size()-1);
                pagination.hasNext = false;
                pagination.hasLast = false;
                pagination.hasPrevious = false;
                pagination.hasFirst = false;
            }
            //If there are more than a page
            else if(articleStartIndex+1 < articles.size()){
                pagination = (ansPKB_Pagination)articles.get(articles.size()-1);
                pagination.hasNext = false;
                pagination.hasLast = false;
            }

        }
    }
    return articles;
}

Class ansPKB_Pagination{

    //Integer pageNumber;
    boolean hasFirst;
    boolean hasPrevious;
    boolean hasNext;
    boolean hasLast;
    List<Object> articles;

    public ansPKB_Pagination(boolean hasFirst,boolean hasPrevious,boolean hasNext,boolean hasLast,List<Object> articles){
        this.hasFirst = hasFirst;
        this.hasPrevious = hasPrevious;
        this.hasNext = hasNext;
        this.hasLast = hasLast;
        this.articles = articles;
    }

}
```

Here is my vf page

```
var sObjects;
var pageNumber=1;

ansPKB_ArticleListingController.articleListing('{!JSENCODE($CurrentPage.parameters.c)}','{!JSENCODE($CurrentPage.parameters.q)}',function(result, event){
    if(event.type == 'exception') {
          console.log(event.message);
    } else {
         sObjects = result;
         console.log(sObjects)
         displayArticles();

    }
},{escape: false});

function displayNext(){
    pageNumber++;
    displayArticles();
}

function displayFirst(){
    pageNumber = 1;
    displayArticles();
}

function displayLast(){
    pageNumber = sObjects.length-1;
    displayArticles();
}

function displayPrevious(){
    pageNumber--;
    displayArticles();
}

//This method displays the values in desired formats
function displayArticles(){

}
```